# Can't get tax_query to work

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom WP Query where I list custom post types. I am trying to set up filters to filter listings by custom taxonomy.

My query setup is as follows:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'opps',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => $postsperpage,
    'posts_per_archive_page' => $postsperpage,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true,
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
    'cache_results'          => true,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => true,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'tax_query'              => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'sector',
                                        'field'    => 'slug',
                                        'terms'    => 'business-services'
                                    ),
                                )
);
```

So in the above example I should get only posts with taxonomy 'sector' with slug 'business-services', but ALL posts from custom post types 'opps' get listed instead.

I have looked everywhere on stackoverflow and beyond but I just can't figure out what I've been doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

I have had this issue before because wordpress does not sync taxonomy terms until late in the init phase. Have you tried running this code in a template, after get_header() or wp_head() has been called? If not try that, it should work then. I know if I've echoed it out in functions.php for testing it will not work because wordpress has not synced tax terms yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have a look at [the codex (`WP_Query`)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) when creating custom queries. As your code stands, it will fail. You have the following issues

- `pagination` is not a valid parameter for `WP_Query`.
- You cannot use `posts_per_page` and `posts_per_archive_page` together
- You don't need to set parameter values that are set by default. Unnecessary parameters used in your code which is by default the default values are `order`, `orderby`, `post_status`, `cache_results`, `update_post_meta_cache` and `update_post_term_cache`

There is no sticky post functionality for custom post types. just remove the `ignore_sticky_post` parameter

Your code should look something like this ( I hope your variables is defined )

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'opps',
    'posts_per_page'         => $postsperpage,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'tax_query'              => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sector',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'business-services'
         ),
      )
);
```